# Using map function with a multi-variable function

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a multi-variable function and i would like to use the map() function with it.

Example:

```
def f1(a, b, c):
    return a+b+c
map(f1, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`itertools.starmap`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) made for this:

```
import itertools

def func1(a, b, c):
    return a+b+c

print list(itertools.starmap(func1, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]))
```

Output:

```
[6, 15, 24]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Use a wrapper.

```
def func1(a, b, c):
    return a+b+c

map((lambda x: func1(*x)), [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply wrap your multi-argument function inside another function that takes just one argument as a tuple/list and then passes it on to the inner function.

```
map(lambda x: func(*x), [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```